# Sublime Text 3: Given a key binding, how to get the command underlying the stroke

Tags: sublimetext3

I just switched from Emacs to ST3

Is there any equivalent to describe-key in Emacs?

Comment: The closest thing i found was this: http://www.sublimetext.com/forum/viewtopic.php?p=22072&sid=4dc6cda0a0cdf51b193a015b91b61a1b#p22072

Comment: @DanGamble Thanks! That's quite helpful!